# JIT error with LINQ OrderBy using C# on iOS

Tags: ios, linq, unity-game-engine, jit

I'm receiving the following error on my iOS device:

> ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2>:GetEnumerator ()' while running with --aot-only.

I'm using Unity3D, and I know the error is caused because LINQ expressions have issues with ordering value types when compiling Unity to iOS. Because (I think) that the expression attempts to use reflection to instantiate a new type which implements the IComparer<TKey> interface. This will work for reference types, but not value types on a Unity iOS build.

So my thought was that since I know in this situation I'm always trying to order a collection of ints. That I could bypass the generic ICompare<TKey> and just create my own custom comparer.

```
public class IntCompare : Comparer<int> {

    public override int Compare (int x, int y)
    {
       return x - y;
    }
}
```

However, using OrderBy still gives me the error. Is there something I'm not understanding on why my method doesn't work?

My expression:

```
OptimizeMaxCommitList(members
                            .OrderBy((memberid) => memberid.Value, new IntCompare())
                            .Skip(1)
                            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                    ,maxCommit);
```

Comment: I know this isn't related, but this is a very well-written question; you not only explained what you want to do, but you explained your reasons, assumptions, and prior approaches. +1 upboats.

Comment: Why not write your own OrderBy extension method and work around that part of LINQ?And worst case, use pre-boxing of the collection to avoid working value types in this critical section

Comment: Thats exactly what I ended up doing, works great now, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of LINQ extension methods from LINQ for Collections are not working with IEnumerables on iOS since they require the AOT runtime compiler which is not supported.

However there is a [LINQ for iOS](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18131) library on Asset Store that is similar to LINQ, but doesn't require a runtime compiler. So you can use it on iOS.

Comment: Great, this wasnt around when i originally asked the question but its a great solution none the less.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer my question directly, but I found a workaround using,

```
members = sortDictionary(members);
OptimizeMaxCommitList(members
                          .Skip(1)
                          .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value),
                      maxCommit);
```

---

```
private Dictionary<string, int> sortDictionary(Dictionary<string, int> members)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list = members.ToList();

    list.Sort((firstPair,nextPair) =>
        {
            return firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
        }
    );

    return list.ToDictionary((keyItem) => keyItem.Key, (valueItem) => valueItem.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, your comparison is broken.

Reading `return (x < y) ? x : y;` you are returning the smallest of the integers, however a comparer is to provide the result of comparing two objects (read: objects as anything you handle, be it `int`, `bool` or `string`).

Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare.aspx), a comparison's return value is defined as:

- **Less than zero**: x is less than y.
- **Zero**: x equals y.
- **Greater than zero**: x is greater than y.

...were x is the first parameter.

Thus your comparison should read `return x - y;` or the sorting algorithm will never terminate with correct results (although it will detect too many iterations and throw an exception complaining that the comparison is broken).

Comment: good catch, I updated my question with what you mentioned. However, Im not getting errors complaining about my comparison being broken, Even after that fixed i still get the same JIT error. So it seems that it isnt even looking at my comparison before throwing the error.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that it most likely wouldn't fix the JIT error.