# Outputting a sorted lists contents

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to output my dictionary values to a Unity string on the GUI (it's for a plug in). When I run my code without the data being outputted to the screen as a GUI label, it runs fine. No errors or anything, however, when I turn on the GUI code, I get the following message in Xcode:

> ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2>:GetEnumerator ()' while running with --aot-only.

I've never experienced this error before, and I'm confused as to what it means. I've googled it, but I couldn't find anything definitive on it.

This is my code as it stands:

```
private string dictionaryString = "I am here!!!!!";
var signalQuailty = dictionary.OrderBy(item => item.Value);

foreach( var v in signalQuailty)
 {
        // Issue line. I want the dictionary to output everything on the screen
        // with every line on a new line
        dictionaryString = "Key value: " + v.Key + " Value: " + v.Value + "\n";
 }

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 410, 1000, 20), dictionaryString);
}
```

Have I done anything wrong?
I don't get the message unless I turn on the string in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `OrderBy` is not supported for the iOS target.
A lot of people have problem using LINQ on iOS, and the general advice is to "use LINQ with care when targeting iOS":

- *[JIT error with LINQ OrderBy using C# on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485517)*
- *[C# in Unity3D – Linq Queries and the Death of the For Loop](http://www.blockypixel.com/2012/09/c-in-unity3d-linq-queries-and-the-death-of-the-for-loop/)*
- *[LINQ stopped working on iOS (after 3.4?)](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/116408-LINQ-stopped-working-on-iOS-%28after-3-4-%29)*